# How to suppress Scalastyle warning?

Tags: scalastyle

I got following code:

```
    string match {
      case Regex(_, "1", "0", _, _)    =>
      case Regex(_, "1", "1", null, _) =>
    }
```

Scalastyle is complaining about usage of null which cannot be avoided here.
Any way I can suppress warning just for this line?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Scalastyle understands suppression comments:

```
// scalastyle:off <rule id>
...
// scalastyle:on <rule id>
```

Rule ids are listed [here](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-dev.html)

In your case, the id is simply null:

```
// scalastyle:off null
...
// scalastyle:on null
```

This was also answered on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scalastyle-users/suppress/scalastyle-users/x23bIgnsddQ/P4JlBP4ditIJ)

Answer (score 39):

For a single line, you just append `// scalastyle:ignore <rule-id>` to the end, like so:

```
string match {
  case Regex(_, "1", "0", _, _)    =>
  case Regex(_, "1", "1", null, _) => // scalastyle:ignore null
}
```

If it's obvious what you want Scalastyle to ignore, you can disable all checks for the current line by omitting the rule-id (as you can for the on/off comments as well):

```
string match {
  case Regex(_, "1", "0", _, _)    =>
  case Regex(_, "1", "1", null, _) => // scalastyle:ignore
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also add a

```
scalastyle_config.xml
```

to your project, and enable/disable any rule. See http://www.scalastyle.org/configuration.html